# How to overlay navigationBar with TableViewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I've set my `navigationBar` background invisible using the following code:

```swift
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

But my `tableView` had an indent and I've lifted it to the top by this:

```swift
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        }
        else {
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        }
```

The problem is that I have a `tabBar` and now `tabBar` overlays my `tableView` too

How can I set `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` only for top? Or should I use another way for lifting `tableView` and make `navigationBar` invisible?

Comment: Can you try `tableView.frame = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.frame`

Comment: @AtalayAsa nothing changed :(